# Rows between two index entries?

Tags: mysql, corruption

I'm having problems re-importing a database dump made by mysqldump. I ran mysqldump with the order-by-primary option, and I had it run on a table with a unique key (and no explicit primary key, so it sorted by that unique key). My objective in this case was to re-create the table, making the unique key into the primary key.

This dump took a very long time (around 10 days) and it would be a major pain in the ass to run it again.  I tried reimporting the dump (with the appropriate schema changes), but mysql choked midway through. I looked in the dumpfile, at the place where it choked - and it looks like someone inserted a spam email right into the text of the dumpfile.

Fortunately, it looks like the damage was isolated, I'm able to see the key right before the garbage, and right after.

**tl;dr**: if I just spliced out the garbage, I dont know how many keys will be missing between the one before and the one after - the dump is sorted by that unique key, so it makes life easier in that respect. Does mysql have a way to retrieve all rows between two entries in an index?

The key is a 32-character hex string, stored in a CHAR(32) type column. I'm pretty sure I can't use the < or > operators on strings... so any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Very sophisticated 1st question. I hope it will find a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting the mysqldump on the primary key (or unique key) is what made it take so long.  Ten days is pretty unbelievable, though.

Doing a sort like this is useful only when you want to backup a MyISAM table and restore it to an InnoDB table.  Is this what you're doing?

MySQL certainly does have a way to dump subsets of a table.  Check out the [`--where`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) option of mysqldump.  This should allow you to back up the rows that got corrupted.

And yes, you can use `<` and `>` on strings in SQL.  You can also use the `BETWEEN` predicate.

Comment: I'm actually dumping from innodb to insert into an innodb table. I had read elsewhere that a order-by-primary is the thing to do when inserting into innodb. It's a 43GB table, so I kind of expected the long delay, I just didn't expect to have to do it twice!

Answer (score 1):

My first question would be, how could a Spam mail make it into your database dump and destroy it?

I am guessing it comes from out of one of your data columns, right? Can you show how this E-Mail and how it managed to disturb your dump's structure?

Maybe it was some sort of header injection that caused the dump to insert line breaks where is shouldn't have, I don't know. Anyway, clearing that up would be first priority in my opinion.

Comment: It's the oddest thing. I did the BETWEEN query as recommended by Bill, and none of the rows appear to have the data that corrupted my dump.

Comment: It's possible the dump file is corrupted, but not the database.